# Is support for ASP.Net in mono being discontinued?

Tags: asp.net, mono, mod-mono, xsp

I was listening to a [recent stack exchange podcast](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/se-podcast-11-2/) episode 11 and sometime during it Joel stated that ASP.Net was officially no longer supported by mono.

I've been looking around and haven't been able to find anything officially stating this.

[Mailing list](http://lists.ximian.com/pipermail/mono-aspnet-list/) still seems active

[XSP](https://github.com/mono/xsp) has commits as recent as July 6

Is asp.net support(or active core team development) actually stopping or was that statement inaccurate?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps this was related to Attachmate laying off all the Mono developers? [Luckily that issue has been resolved.](http://www.i-programmer.info/news/89-net/2755-attachmate-do-the-right-thing-for-mono.html)

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET is still actively developed, especially ASP.NET MVC 3. Don't know why Joel stated this.

Comment: This question isn't about ASP.NET development itself, it's about the Mono project and its support for ASP.NET.